# web application asp.net filling viewdata in javascript bloc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-applications, viewdata

I'm new to asp.net MVC webapplications, and I'm trying, if it is possible of course, to do something like this `ViewData["MyData"] = ViewData[LocalJavascriptVariable]`

The ViewData[LocalJavascriptVariable] is already filled in the controller and the LocalJavascriptVariable is set depending on user's choice in the view I hope it's clear and that there is a solution to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Your explanation of the issue isn't very clear. Could you expand your example further please?

Comment: First, i'm sorry for my bad explanation. 
I think the most simple way to ask it is can we fill the ViewData in a javascript bloc ? 
But with details, I have an onchange function in which I want (each time it's called) to change the data stocked in my ViewData["MyData"] and fill it with data from another ViewData[X]. X is a javascript variable, set depending on user's choice (I made sure that for all the possible values of X, ViewData[X] contains data)

Answer (score 0):

The ViewData object only exists on the server and is not directly accessible from the web browser.

You would need to have the users input sent to the server some how, depending on the use case, an ajax (XMLHttpRequest) to a WebAPI endpoint or a normal form submission to a method on your controller.